# google blogger API rate limit exceeded

Tags: api, blogger

I use the API for 50 posts per day. all my limits as mentioned in the google API console page are in order and have not been violated, yet I cannot post and the reply I get is {

```
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
"message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
```

What should I do ? I have sent mails but no reply has come.

Answer (score 2):

You can [email a Googler directly](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/bloggerdev/7xpbeC4TVJI) to request the 50 API limit be raised. The suggestion of having useful content on your blog when requesting implies that the limit is there to prevent constant spam / attempts to raise search ranking etc.

Comment: but the limits page claims that I am allowed 10k posts per day.

Comment: Do you have a link for that? The blogger API service allows 10k *API requests* a day when enabling it in the API console but there is an additional limit of 50 blog post requests a day that can be manually lifted by Google.

Comment: :(. have sent mails. lets see if they allow me more posts. Is there a link where this limit of posts is mentioned as I had checked out a lot of sites and could not find anything like this. Anyways thanks a lot for the information. Lets hope they raise the quota for me.

Comment: This page seems related only to user-interactive posts (not API) http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=42348 I don't see anything official but others have hit the 50 post API limit: https://www.google.com/search?q=google+blogger+api+posts+limit

Answer (score 0):

The quota per API key is different to the per-blog quota of post creations. One API key can send a large number of requests (Its over 9000!, as you said), across multiple users, but a blog can only create a certain number of posts a day.

Answer (score 0):

There is another limit of 100 of requests per 100 seconds per user. You can get "User Rate Limit Exceeded" from it too.